# Android internet connectivity check

Tags: android, connection

am trying to check for available internet connection, i find many subjects speaking about this, but i still have a problem when i try to verify for the internet connection, the code am using is the flowing:

```java
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() &&    conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

How can help me please ?
PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @MattBall the problem is:NullPointer...

Comment: @Sam Yes Internet permission and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE are set on the manifest file

Comment: Please post your logcat errors. Your code snippet executes, I believe your null pointer is somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Your method is correct. Also you'll need in your android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But keep in mind that low signal, server downtime, captive portals, content filters, other network problems can prevent your application from reaching a server. So having an active network interface doesn't guarantee that a particular networked service is available.

Comment: With the code mentioned in the question - i get isOnline as True - although other apps on my mobile correctly identify 'No internet connection'

Answer (score 0):

In this code you have red status in private var:

```
    private boolean mIsConnected;
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
            super.onResume();

            //red status broadcast
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
            registerReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver, filter);
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo =
                    (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            mIsConnected= networkInfo.isConnected();
            Log.i("TAG", String.format("Status red: %b", mIsConnected))

        }
    };
```